# Rotation of hair particles when animating with an armature

Tags: armature, particles, hair

I've been struggling with this one for a couple days, and can't seem to solve it. I'm modeling/rigging a pigeon and intend to use particle systems to create the hair on the body and feathers. The trouble is that when I animate it with an armature, the the hair particles either retain their initial orientation (i.e. *do* move with the armature but *do not* rotate accordingly) or are influenced by a bone on the opposite side of the rig. There is seemingly no rhyme or reason to which particles are affected, except that they do unanimously follow the rotation of the root bone.

[image]

I initially tried this with combed hair particles, but this locked in many of the settings and made it more difficult to test. Hence, this simplified setup.

[image]

Comment: your problem that 'the hair particles are influenced by a bone on the opposite side of the rig' may be caused because the mesh has weight assigned to two bones. It may be solved if you change the weight paint such that it is assigned to one bone only

Comment: Thanks Faceb. That may work for the individual feathers, but I think I would have some trouble when it came to the body, since it's controlled by several bones whose weights blend together. One idea I came across was to use separate "scalp" objects as emitters parented to the individual bones, but I don't think that will generate ideal results either.